# Primeng paginator cannot reset page 1 after call API

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have 2 functions to load data: when init page and search page. 
When init page, the data display with 5 pages. I click page 3, the data show with paging is Ok. After that, enter data search. The data table is reload, but the page number does not reset to 1, it's still page 3.
in html:

```
<p-paginator rows="5" totalRecords="{{totalRecords}}"  (onLazyLoad)="paginate($event)"
 (onPageChange)="paginate($event)" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[2,5,10,20]"></p-paginator>
```

ts:

```
 defaultPage:0;
 defaultSize:2
paginate(event) {
 let currentPage: number;
    this.defaultPage = event.first / event.rows;
    this.defaultSize = event.rows;
    this.listData = [];
    if (this.isSearch == 1) {
      this.getLoadPageSearch(this.defaultSize, this.defaultPage);
    } else {
      this.getLoadPage(this.defaultSize, this.defaultPage);
    }
}
```

Please adivice me how to reset the paginator after call another API

Comment: You will need to assign a reference `#p` to your component and call `p.changePageToFirst()`: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/paginator/paginator.ts#L179

Comment: Here is a sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/zmiMcSqW0MzurXhxDVTJ?p=preview

Comment: @Brian: thank you Brian, this demo is well. But I have an issue when add this code :[ts] Property 'changePageToFirst' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.

Comment: Try getting rid of the type ElementRef when you define the ViewChild (if that doesn't work, assign `any` as the type.

Comment: @Brian: it works without error with code: @ViewChild('pg') paginator: any;. But after call reset, it show a error in console:core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined. Pls advice me. many thanks

Comment: Bad tagging. How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: @Brian: i just add event in to function: this.paginator.changePageToFirst(event); and it works well .Thank you so much. Could you add this answer to post Answer section? I will mark it.

Comment: @Kukeltje: tks, i just change it by primeng

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The p-paginator component contains the `changePageToFirst` function. To access this function, we will need to obtain a ViewChild reference to the component. For example, in our template we define the component:

```
<p-paginator rows="10" totalRecords="100" #p></p-paginator>
<button (click)="reset($event)">Reset</button>
```

And in our component, we can handle the reset event as follows:

```
@ViewChild('p', {static: false}) paginator: Paginator;

reset($event) {
    this.paginator.changePageToFirst($event);
}
```

Here is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/FxwTHK0W2WuTCjuqhLp6?p=preview

EDIT: The above demo is no longer working on plunkr. Here is an updated version:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9nqf5

Comment: Awesome. How did you find this?

Comment: The source for the component can be found here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/paginator/paginator.ts#L179

Comment: This is not availble in PrimeNg v7.1

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator

Comment: It looks like this method is still present in 7.1. However, it is not documented: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/a74a0df32baaff40ce2e9f6a909be2b105263e3b/src/app/components/paginator/paginator.ts#L184

Comment: In the meantime (at least Angular 8 and higher) `@ViewChild` needs a second argument. So you may use 
`@ViewChild('p', {static: false}) paginator: Paginator;`.

Comment: How can we use this with table, i am using p-table with paginator, how can i access the paginator element which is inside table

Comment: Hi Muhammed, you can get a reference by labeling your p-paginator component with a directive (eg: #my-paginator). Then, in your component you can access the Paginator object using the @ViewChild decorator, eg: @ViewChild('my-paginator', {static: false}) paginator: Paginator;

You will need to import ViewChild and the Paginator components

Answer (score 7):

Another useful method is **changePage**.

In template:

```
<p-paginator #pp></p-paginator>
```

In the component:

```
@ViewChild('pp') paginator: Paginator;

this.paginator.changePage(0);
```

Comment: What if the paginator has onPageChange event registered? It is going into recursion.

Comment: You right, is the correct anwser, thanks..

Comment: Awesome this works thanks. Bizarre it's not part of the default component.

Answer (score 5):

For those using the dataTable primeng component and using its lazy pagination feature,
we can reset the page to '1' by using

```
this.tableTemplateName.first = 0;
```

where setting `first=0` means first page